# Disaggregate data from yearly to monthly basis

Tags: r, date, spotfire, unpivot

I have data from projects that should report year savings of a certain amount.
I need to separate the data from yearly to monthly basis accounting from the month the initiative started to 12 month later. The amount of each month's saving is just the yearly savings divided by 12 for simplicity.

I need to do this either in Tibco.Spotfire or R.

Eg: I need to go from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The following solution should work. It requires `data.table` and `lubridate`. Within Spotfire, you can install both of these using Tools -> TERR Tools -> Package Management. Setting up a data function in Spotfire has plenty of resources (https://datashoptalk.com/spotfire-data-functions-terr-basics/)

```
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Initiative = c('A', 'B') ,
                 start_date = c(as.Date('2017/1/1'), as.Date('2015/5/1')),
                 Savings = c(240, 120)
                 )

new_dt <- dt[, .( 
       Date = seq.Date(start_date, as.Date(start_date %m+% months(11)), by = 'month'),
       Monthly_Savings = Savings / 12), by = Initiative]

new_dt

    Initiative       Date Monthly_Savings
 1:          A 2017-01-01              20
 2:          A 2017-02-01              20
 3:          A 2017-03-01              20
 4:          A 2017-04-01              20
 5:          A 2017-05-01              20
 6:          A 2017-06-01              20
 7:          A 2017-07-01              20
 8:          A 2017-08-01              20
 9:          A 2017-09-01              20
10:          A 2017-10-01              20
11:          A 2017-11-01              20
12:          A 2017-12-01              20
13:          B 2015-05-01              10
14:          B 2015-06-01              10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution in R using tidyverse:

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(lubridate, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# Creating your data ------------------------------------------------------

data <- tibble(
  initiative = c("A", "B"),
  starting_date = c("may-18", "jun-17"),
  savings = c(240, 120)
) 

data
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   initiative starting_date savings
#>   <chr>      <chr>           <dbl>
#> 1 A          may-18            240
#> 2 B          jun-17            120

# Formatting starting_date as date ----------------------------------------

data <- 
  data %>% 
  mutate(
    starting_date = my(starting_date)
  )

data
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   initiative starting_date savings
#>   <chr>      <date>          <dbl>
#> 1 A          2018-05-01        240
#> 2 B          2017-06-01        120

# Disaggregate ------------------------------------------------------------

data <- 
  data %>% 
  group_by(initiative) %>%
  summarise(
    initiative = rep(initiative, 12),
    date = seq.Date(
      from = starting_date, 
      to = starting_date %m+% months(11), 
      by = "month"
    ),
    monthly_savings = rep(savings/12)
  ) %>% 
  ungroup() 
#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'initiative'. You can override using the `.groups` argument.

data %>% 
  print(n = Inf)
#> # A tibble: 24 x 3
#>    initiative date       monthly_savings
#>    <chr>      <date>               <dbl>
#>  1 A          2018-05-01              20
#>  2 A          2018-06-01              20
#>  3 A          2018-07-01              20
#>  4 A          2018-08-01              20
#>  5 A          2018-09-01              20
#>  6 A          2018-10-01              20
#>  7 A          2018-11-01              20
#>  8 A          2018-12-01              20
#>  9 A          2019-01-01              20
#> 10 A          2019-02-01              20
#> 11 A          2019-03-01              20
#> 12 A          2019-04-01              20
#> 13 B          2017-06-01              10
#> 14 B          2017-07-01              10
#> 15 B          2017-08-01              10
#> 16 B          2017-09-01              10
#> 17 B          2017-10-01              10
#> 18 B          2017-11-01              10
#> 19 B          2017-12-01              10
#> 20 B          2018-01-01              10
#> 21 B          2018-02-01              10
#> 22 B          2018-03-01              10
#> 23 B          2018-04-01              10
#> 24 B          2018-05-01              10
```

I have kept your dates as `yyyy.mm.dd`, but you can get them back to the format you had with `data %>% mutate(date = format(date, "%b-%y"))`.